# Powershell: Seemingly valid parameter set doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I am putting together a set of tools for internal account management. This particular cmdlet will prep an account for a transfer out, which includes an option to remove or retain their groups. My `Param` statement has become quite lengthy and has ended up with 6 parameter sets to cover every scenario. All combinations of parameters are working except for one. Here is my code:

```
function Move-AccountOut {

    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferHomeDrive')]
    Param( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,Position=1)]
        [string]$Username,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups',Position=2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran',Position=2)]
        [switch]$RetainGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroups',Position=2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran',Position=2)]
        [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Position=3)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran', Position=3)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran', Position=3)]
        [switch]$TransferHomeDrive,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True, Position=4)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran', Mandatory=$True, Position=4)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran', Mandatory=$True, Position=4)]
        [string]$OldServer,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True, Position=5)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran', Mandatory=$True, Position=5)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran', Mandatory=$True, Position=5)]
        [string]$NewServer
    )
}
```

Which will generate the following `Get-Help` output:

```
Move-AccountOut [-Username] <string>  [<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut [-Username] <string> [[-RetainGroups]] [[-TransferHomeDrive]] [-OldServer] <string> [-NewServer] <string>  [<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut [-Username] <string> [[-RetainGroups]]  [<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut [-Username] <string> [[-RemoveFromAllGroups]] [[-TransferHomeDrive]] [-OldServer] <string> [-NewServer] <string>  [<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut [-Username] <string> [[-RemoveFromAllGroups]]  [<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut [-Username] <string> [[-TransferHomeDrive]] [-OldServer] <string> [-NewServer] <string>  [<CommonParameters>]
```

The parameter I am having trouble with is the bottom one (transfer only). I can run the command with username, username+retain, username+remove, username+retain+transfer and username+remove+transfer. But transfer without a retain or remove does not work. When run, it throws the following error:

```
Move-AccountOut : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:33 char:1
+ Move-AccountOut -Username X -TransferHomeDrive -OldServer X -NewServer Y
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-AccountOut], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Move-AccountOut
```

I can't figure out why, given that it appears to be a valid parameter set according to my `Get-Help` output.

Comment: Try doing a trace: `Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression { Move-AccountOut -Username X -TransferHomeDrive -OldServer X -NewServer Y } -PSHost` and post the output.

Comment: @briantist http://pastebin.com/NiKTCajP

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the output, here is the key (emphasis mine):

> Remaining valid parameter set: **RetainGroupsWTran**
>   Remaining valid parameter set: **RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran**
>   Remaining valid parameter set: **TransferHomeDrive**

This happens after all parameters have been bound, and it shows that there are 3 valid parameter sets remaining.

**TransferHomeDrive** is the parameter set you want.

So why are the other ones there?

**RetainGroupsWTran** *should* only be possible if `-RetainGroups` is specified, and **RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran** *should* only be possible if `-RemoveFromAllGroups` is specified.

However, you can also see in the `Get-Help` output that there is no parameter set where those switches are mandatory, and this is the problem.

Your updated definition looks like the following:

```powershell
function Move-AccountOut {

    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferHomeDrive')]
    Param( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,Position=1)]
        [string]$Username,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups',Position=2)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran',Position=2)]
        [switch]$RetainGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroups',Position=2)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran',Position=2)]
        [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Position=3)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran', Position=3)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran', Position=3)]
        [switch]$TransferHomeDrive,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True, Position=4)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran', Mandatory=$True, Position=4)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran', Mandatory=$True, Position=4)]
        [string]$OldServer,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True, Position=5)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran', Mandatory=$True, Position=5)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran', Mandatory=$True, Position=5)]
        [string]$NewServer
    )
}
```

I've made them mandatory within the parameter sets that were showing up in the trace output.

I think that you should also make them mandatory in the `RetainGroups` and `RemoveFromAllGroups` parameter sets as well, but it's not shown above.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the trick, with one quirk: When I run the cmdlet with `-TransferHomeDrive` by itself, it still throws an ambiguous parameter set error. When I run it with `-OldServer` and `-NewServer` it runs fine? New pastebin: http://pastebin.com/bvm86Qac

Comment: `-OldServer` and `-NewServer` are mandatory for the `TransferHomeDrive` parameter set. I think I recall in your other question that I made that assumption based on what you wrote, but I wasn't sure about it. As long as those parameters are mandatory in that set, you'll need to specify them. You can made them optional instead (only in `TransferHomeDrive`), should work, but I haven't worked out if there will be any side effects.